# What is the best way to loop through object instances in Python?

Tags: python

I am very new to Python so please bear with me if you can.  I have created a class called `team` that has 4 attributes `(city, teamname, wins, losses)`.  I've created 5 instances of `team` `(team_1, team_2, team_3, team_4, team_5)` and have initialized their attributes.  See the code below.  I am looking for a way to loop through the instances and produce an output that lists the teams by ascending order of wins.  I'm not sure if the best way to do this would be to somehow create a list or dictionary from the instances or if there is a more efficient way to loop through the instances.  Again I am extremely green when it comes to Python and would very much appreciate any help I can get.  Thank you in advance for your time!

```
class team:

    def __init__(self, city, teamname, wins, losses):
        self.city = city
        self.teamname = teamname
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses

team_1 = team('Boston','Red Sox', 162, 0)
team_2 = team('New York', 'Yankees', 0, 162)
team_3 = team('Tampa Bay', 'Rays', 80, 82)
team_4 = team('Toronto', 'Blue Jays', 82, 80)
team_5 = team('Baltimore', 'Orioles', 1, 161)
```

Comment: Putting the instances in a list would seem like an obvious and natural way to handle them.

Comment: definitely sounds like the way to do it, I guess I'm having trouble figuring out how to put them in a list.  I could obviously manually create a list but I would like to be able to iterate through them and add them to a list that way.  I'm not sure how to iterate through object instances and read them to a list.

Comment: `teams = []; teams.append(team('Boston', 'Red Sox', etc)); teams.append(...)` or just put the initializers straight in the list like `teams = [team('Boston', ...), team('New York', ...), ... ]`

Comment: @Chuck0185 if you start off by creating them as separate global variables, it's always going to be tricky to work with them. It might be best to put them in a list or dict, right from the start, e.g. `teams = [team('Boston', ...), team('New York', ...), ...]`

Answer (score 1):

Python has built in sorting with `sorted`
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

You can pass it a key. So here we go:

```
class Team: # Capitalize your class names

    def __init__(self, city, teamname, wins, losses):
        self.city = city
        self.teamname = teamname
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses

team_list = [Team('Boston','Red Sox', 162, 0), 
             Team('New York', 'Yankees', 0, 162),
             Team('Tampa Bay', 'Rays', 80, 82),
             Team('Toronto', 'Blue Jays', 82, 80),
             Team('Baltimore', 'Orioles', 1, 161)]

def sort_key(x):
  return x.wins

teams_sorted = sorted(team_list, key=sort_key)
print([x.city for x in teams_sorted])
# ['New York', 'Baltimore', 'Tampa Bay', 'Toronto', 'Boston']
```

Answer (score 1):

As many have mentioned in the comments, Creating a list and iterating through is the most simple way to go about it.

```
team_list = []
team_list.append(team('Boston','Red Sox', 162, 0))
team_list.append(team('Boston','Red Sox', 162, 0))
team_list.append(team('New York', 'Yankees', 0, 162))
team_list.append(team('Tampa Bay', 'Rays', 80, 82))
team_list.append(team('Toronto', 'Blue Jays', 82, 80))
team_list.append(team('Baltimore', 'Orioles', 1, 161))

# For sorting the teams
sorted_team = sorted(team_list, key=lambda team: team.wins)
print([team.city for team in sorted_team])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the operator `<` (less than) in a class like this:

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, city, teamname, wins, losses):
        self.city = city
        self.teamname = teamname
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.wins < other.wins

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.teamname # or what you want to show
```

This way python knows how to sort a list of objects from this class.

```
sorted_list = sorted([team_1, team_2, team_3, team_4, team_5])
```

Also by defining the representation operator python knows what to show when the print function is called upon one of these objects.

Comment: how would I call the function?  confused as to how I would return the list sorted by wins

Comment: By defining the operator you can compare objects, for example `team_1 < team_2` will evaluate to `False`, as `team_1` has more wins than `team_2`. This way, the `sorted` function applied over the list of teams will be able to compare and sort the team objects.

Comment: I guess what I meant was that if I print sorted_list it gives me the memory location of all of the instances.  How would I print out the teamnames or the cities?

Comment: Oh, my bad. You can go with the approaches in the other answers or define the `__repr__` operator, I edited my answer so when you print `sorted_list` it shows the name of each team.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list, then `append()` each new team object onto the list:

```
teams = []
teams.append(team('Boston','Red Sox', 162, 0))
teams.append(team('New York', 'Yankees', 0, 162))
teams.append(team('Tampa Bay', 'Rays', 80, 82))
teams.append(team('Toronto', 'Blue Jays', 82, 80))
teams.append(team('Baltimore', 'Orioles', 1, 161))
```